# Java Calendar View strange behaviour

Tags: javafx, calendar, jfoenix

I'm using a JavaFX calendar widget from JFoenix but for a few days, I get an extraordinary display output. There are strange symbols shown, but I get this error only on my system. When sending the jar to other PCs it works fine.
Maybe someone has an idea whats wrong or has seen a similar problem.
[image]

Comment: My best guess would be a misconfigured locale or missing/corrupted font.

Comment: When i click on number, the correct date is written in the top edit textefield, so the time format should be correct. And because it can display numbers i don't think it's a font problem...

Comment: I am having the same issue as well..have you managed to fix it?